# does heroku support jruby for Rails 3.2.3?

Tags: heroku, jruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Does heroku support jruby. I am trying to implement a Rails 3.2.3 app using jruby on heroku but I get following error

```
2012-04-03T20:21:02+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (no such file to load -- java) (LoadError)
```

how do i solve this problem?
here is my `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
gem 'devise'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
 group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

 # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 gem 'therubyrhino'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking into this a bit as well, and found this link to be helpful
https://github.com/jkutner/jruby-trinidad-heroku

It shows how to get a rack app running on trindad/jruby
git clone git://github.com/jkutner/jruby-trinidad-heroku.git
BUNDLER_GEMFILE=Jemfile bundle
gem install heroku
heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java
git push heroku master

I realize you are trying to do rails, not rack, but I think this would be a good starting place. If you can get this to work, then you can try to bring in just rails (no db), and slowly build it up.

Unless someone has a more complete example of Rails on jRuby on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku supports build pack so that we can run most of languages. You can use JRuby build pack to install your app: http://carlhoerberg.github.com/blog/2012/03/29/run-jruby-on-heroku/